# Sorting a list of objects

Tags: c#, list, sorting, object

I'm trying to sort a list of objects depending on the return value of a method (call it Q()) in the classes that instantiate the object. Both classes Decaf and Regular derive from the same class, Coffee. The two derived classes also have different implementations of the method in question, Q(). It looks like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
      Decaf decafCoffee = null;
      Regular regularCoffee = null;
      List<Coffee> inventory = new List<Coffee>();
      if (type.StartsWith("D:"))
      {
          // The value of M changes based on certain criteria
          decafCoffee = new Decaf(name, D, C, M);
          inventory.Add(decafCoffee);
      }
      else if (type.StartsWith("R:"))
      {
          regularCoffee = new Regular(name, D, C, M);
          inventory.Add(regularCoffee);
      }   

      for (int j = 0; j < inventory.Count; j++)
      {
          Console.WriteLine("{0}", inventory[j].toString());
      }         
}
```

How can I sort this list by the value of the method Q() in the two classes in increasing order? I can post class code if need be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest method is probably to use Linq's [`OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby.aspx) method:

```
var sorted = inventory.OrderBy(i => i.Q());
```

This will return an `IEnumerable` -- if you want a `List` just do this:

```
var sortedList = inventory.OrderBy(i => i.Q()).ToList();
```

Comment: Much faster than IComparable!

Comment: Much less horrible than IComparable!

Answer (score 0):

Implement IComparable interface in both classes and use .Sort method.

Here is an example.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42839/Sorting-Lists-using-IComparable-and-IComparer-Inte